# Storing data source credentials times out

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, powerbi

I'm experiencing the following problem:

- We created an **Azure SQL database** and put some dummy data in.
- In **Power BI Desktop** we add the data source and create a sample report.
- We publish to **Power BI service**.
- In the browser, we can look at the report. But when we try to **refresh the data source**, it tells us that our credentials are wrong/missing.
- Now, when I try to enter the credentials, nothing happens for many minutes and it appears to **time out**.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea for what could be causing this issue?

Update: Appears to be a known issue https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Storing-data-source-credentials-times-out/m-p/434497#M46324

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that we separated the port with a colon (industry standard) instead of a comma. PowerBi Desktop accepted the colon without complaining, PowerBi online did not.